# Calling a procedure with objects as arguments

Tags: delphi

Trying to save code.  I want to display text etc on an image on the form at OnActivate then print the same text on clicking button (Real program is more complicated).  To save writing code twice I tried the enclosed code but it won't compile at the "Obj.Canvas" line.  If I comment out this line and the enclosed line the program runs but the Obj value is ().

I've tried several other approaches but none work. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Badger

```
unit Unit7;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, printers;

type
  TForm7 = class(TForm)
    Print: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    PrintDialog1: TPrintDialog;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PrintClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    DH,DW:Extended;
    Procedure DoLayout(Obj:TObject);
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
DoLayout(Image1);
end;

procedure TForm7.PrintClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    printer.BeginDoc;
      DoLayout(Printer);
    Printer.EndDoc;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm7.DoLayout(Obj:TObject);
begin
  if  Obj =Printer then         //when you run the program Obj is ()
  begin
    DW:=Printer.PageWidth/Image1.Width;
    DH:=Printer.PageHeight/Image1.Height;
  end
  else
  begin
    DH:=1;
    DW:=1;
  end;
  With Obj.canvas do          //Error here when compiled   - tried commenting it out
  begin
    TextOut(Int(DH*50),Int(DW*30),'This is the text');    //commented this out too
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: An instance of TObject does not have a canvas property, which explains the error; you need to pick the correct canvas object, rather than what you're doing.

Comment: I bow to your wisdom re TObject having no canvas.  However, it doesn't solve my problem. I need the DoLayout procedure to work for Image1 and Printer otherwise I would just have kept the doLayout as part of the print procedure.

Comment: Your problem is that you pass in a TObject, because TPrinter and TImage do not have a common ancestor. Object does not have a Canvas, and the compiler doesn't know what you actually pass in, so that doesn't work. But they have a Canvas in common, so pass that, together with the necessary data to perform the layout, IOW, do what Petesh's answer says.

Comment: FWIW, comments are merely comments, They are not meant to contain a solution to your problem. For that, there are answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TPrinter` class and the `TImage` class don't share a common ancestor class except for `TObject`, as a result that's what you're passing in.

A suggested refactoring is to change the `DoLayout` code to accept the canvas that you want to use, as well as an parameter to determine if it's a printer or an image that you're passing in e.g.

```
procedure TForm7.DoLayout(aCanvas : TCanvas; bPrinter : boolean);
begin
  if bPrinter then         //when you run the program Obj is ()
  begin
    DW:=Printer.PageWidth/Image1.Width;
    DH:=Printer.PageHeight/Image1.Height;
  end
  else
  begin
    DH:=1;
    DW:=1;
  end;
  With aCanvas do
  begin
    TextOut(Int(DH*50),Int(DW*30),'This is the text');
  end;
end;
```

then when you call it, use the printer canvas explicitly, or the image canvas:

```
DoLayout(Printer.canvas, true);
```

or

```
DoLayout(Image1.canvas, false);
```

this is just a rough estimation based on your code; I don't have a delphi compiler to hand to verify it.